# List of properties of list items in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm getting a list of files in applescript like so:

```
set _resourcesFolder to folder (((path to me) as string) & "Contents:Resources:")
set _signatureFiles to files of _resourcesFolder whose name extension is in {"html", "webarchive"}
```

Then I want to get the properties these items in separate lists. Tried it like so:

```
set _signatureNames to displayed name of _signatureFiles
set _signatureDate to modification date of _signatureFiles
```

This doesn't work. But this does:

```
set _signatureNames to displayed name of files of _resourcesFolder whose name extension is in {"html", "webarchive"}
set _signatureDate to modification date of files of _resourcesFolder whose name extension is in {"html", "webarchive"}
```

Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first snippet, you define two lists: **_resourcesFolder** and **_signatureFiles**

In your second snippet, your code is asking for the displayed name and the modification date of one of those lists.  This fails because you are addressing the list, not the items in the list.

In your third snippet, you correctly address the items individually, and all is swell.

The only other method available (based on your original snippet) is to repeat through the files in **_signatureFiles** and create the lists or records as part of the repeat.  Your code in the third snippet is the only way to do it in a single command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.